# Spring Batch. Create job with steps dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I think to use Spring batch within my application to run Jobs(Spring Batch) with set\number of Steps(Spring Batch) to generate some test data(clients\users).
As example:

*Job 1(create client one)*

```
Step 1 Create client in database

Step 2 Set client lastname

Step 3 Set client firstname

Step 4 Set client middle name
```

*Job 2(create client two)*

```
Step 1 Create client in database

Step 2 Set client lastname

Step 3 Set client phonenumber
```

So, corresponding to Spring Batch examples I do have to configure context file(batch-context.xml), where I explicitly will define configuration for Job and Steps(Flow).

But what I want:

*Generate Steps dynamically.*

I want to have Json file where I will have instructions - set of my Steps(Spring Batch steps) in order I want to execute them sequentially inside one Spring Job and Spring Batch reads Json file understands which Steps have to be executed(from Json file) and execute tham inside Job(Spring Batch).

Is it possible to do so within Spring Batch? If yes. Do you have any examples?

Comment: Those examples look like a single step to me where a) Reader gets input from JSON file to represent the request; b) Processor create a new client object and populate the desired fields (which fields to populate is based on the request from the Reader); c) Writer persists the client properties to a database.  A tasklet could also be used if all instructions are in a single JSON file instead of JSON file for each client.

Comment: Hello Andrew. Thank you for your answer. What if there is not only one json file but two or even more of them(json files). How can I manage the Reader for to many variations of json file. Just I think I will define lots of logic inside one Reader - Processor - Writer for two many cases\profiles(json files).

Comment: The Reader would consume each JSON file - [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-multiresourceitemreader-example/) is an example based on multiple CSV files.

Comment: Thank you for your help Andrew

Comment: @user_1234567_java is your issue solved with Andrew's comments?

Comment: Partly yes. He gave me some thoughts ti think about.

Comment: I want to have a job consisting of Steps which will create a client for me. To create a client I need to execute number of Steps like: Step1 - Invoke a Rest service, Step 2 - Call DB function, Step 3 - Again call Rest service, Step 4 - Put message to MQ queue and so on....
But the point is here is that the order are different every time, the order of Steps and also what integration(rest, soap, db, mq) I will invoke i will define is supperate\individual  Json file(Input\Description file).  But from my point of view, why I choose Batch, cuz it has everything i need: Listeners, JobRespotory..